# Bash grep avoid checking directories

Tags: bash, grep

I'm getting errors because I search through sub directories and I don't want it to search those just the files that are in this folder.  The other folders are LOGS and RESULTS and contain other files.  How do you stop to just search the files in Downloads?

```
is_file_contains_VAR()
{
grep -q -e "$VAR" "$1"

}

for f in *
do
   if [ -f "$f" ]; then
      if is_file_contains_VAR"$f"; then
    echo "FILE exist in " $f

    #echo "Processing $f file..."

        # take action on each file. $f store current file name
    #cat $f
    else
        echo "echo "FILE DOES NOT exist in " $f
     fi

 done
```

Comment: So it's searching recursively even though the -r flag isn't present?

Comment: I think grep is doing whatever I put into the function. So either grep must disregard and no output anything on folders and sub folders or not pass any variables to function that has grep inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
cd Downloads/
for f in *
do
   [[ -f "$f" ]] && is_file_contains_VAR "$f" && echo "found"
done
```

**EDIT:**

```
for f in *
do
   if [ -f "$f" ]; then
      if is_file_contains_VAR "$f"; then
          echo "FILE exist in $f"
      else
          echo "echo "PATTERN DOES NOT exist in $f"
      fi
   fi
done
```

Comment: how do I use this with "then"  My code is : for f in *
do
   [[ -f "$f" ]] && is_file_contains_VAR "$f" ; then
        echo "File exist in "$f

Comment: I get this error. I will post all of my code above ./tedown1: line 121: conditional binary operator expected
./tedown1: line 121: syntax error near `"$f"'

Comment: But that is name of your function `is_file_contains_VAR` right. Let me make another edit.

Comment: Getting different error, I'm using "else", if the file if the function is false.  Getting this error.  ./tedown1: line 130: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./tedown1: line 140: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: You have one `fi` missing, see my answer.

Comment: if I leave else I still get that EOF but I don't think the files in the directory are ever getting to the function even after I take the else out.  What does "-f" do?

Comment: Okay it works...I check my grep function and I commented out for troubleshooting.  It works.

Answer (score 4):

Add a

```
[ -d "$f" ] && continue
```

at the beginning of your loop.  If `$f` is a directory, it will get skipped.

Btw, you might consider what device files, fifos and symbolic links should result in.  Maybe you want to use `[ -f "$f" ] || continue` to only check regular files (and symbolic links to regular files).

Comment: What is this called -f -d?  Where do I get more info on these commands? I probably don't need any more then files because the files are current files that I just created previously in the script. But I'm interested in more info. Thanks!

Comment: `[ ... ]` is just another way of calling `test ...`, so have a look at `man test` or `man bash` (and in there search for the built-in command `test`).

Comment: To be clearer:  You can also use `test -d "$f" && continue`; it has the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `find` instead of the general `*` to iterate over specifically files:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 |
while read -d '' -r file; do
    do_something_with "$file"
done
```

`-maxdepth 1` stops find from descending into subdirectories.

I assume GNU find.

Always quote your `"$variables"` unless you specifcally know when to not quote them.